# Automatic/timed reload of tableView from model?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am working on an application which uses a singleton data model and two controllers (one a mapView and the other a tableView) both configured using a UITabBarController. I have setup a delegate on the mapView to acquire CLLocation data and add it to an NSMutableArray in the data model. I want to add this data as cells to the tableView, I have accesses to the data via the shared model so that is not a problem. My question is:

*(1) is there a way to automatically update the tableView as new data goes into the model (NSMutableArray)?*

## EDIT:

I have just been thinking about this and it looks to me like I should be using the model as the delegate for the CLLoctionManager, storing the data in the NSMutableArray as I detailed above. That way both the MapView and the TableView have access to the data. Can anyone help me with reloading the tableView, is there an automatic / timer way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's a reloadData method on a UITableView which you can use to force it to reload its data.

However as a suggestion, rather than using a timer why not implement your own protocol/delegate as a part of your model class. (Here's a pretty good tutorial on [using custom delegates in Objective-C](http://jonsterling.github.com/2009/08/01/using-custom-delegates-in-objective-c.html), although from memory I *think* it omits a [someObject setDelegate:self] somewhere along the way.)

You could make the view controller that's responsible for the table view a delegate for your model, which would inform the view controller that the underlying data has changed and that a reload is required. The view controller would then presumably inform the user (spinning wheel 'o' happy, etc.) and call reloadData on the table as required.

Comment: Much appreciated, you both answered my question and gave me a little food for thought, thank you.

Comment: @fuzzygoat - Glad to be of help. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it by registering your view that contains the tableView for notifications.

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                      selector:@selector(yourSelector:) 
                                      name:@"addedData" 
                                      object:nil];
```

Then implement your selector:

```
- (void)yourSelector:(NSNotification *)notification {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    //do something
}
```

Now in the class where the data is added, you post a notification that new data was added.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"addedData" 
                                      object:nil];
```

Comment: +1 @sudo - Out of interest, is there a general rule as to when to use a notification rather than a delegate? (Presume it's if multiple objects are likely to need to be informed.)

Comment: Yes I believe you hit the nail.  You can pass along an object when you post notifications, but if multiple objects need to be passed I guess it'd not be the best way.  However, I believe you can add multiple observers for the same notification. :)

Comment: Thats very iteresting, I might just use this in this case, but as middaparka points out delegates are useful also, I certainly ned to read up a little more on their use. Much appreciated Sudo

Comment: No problem, hope it helps. =)